# Responsive images in bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have different image sizes in a div in a bootstrap carousel. It is either landscape or portrait images and if I set the width to be 100% the landscape images become perfect but the portraits to high.

And if I set max-hight to it the lanscape images doesn't become full width.

[Link to Wep-page](https://www.officeofpossibilities.se/sm-test/)

CSS:

```
.case-box {
margin-bottom: 1.5em;
display: flex;
width: 100%;
height: 420px;
align-items: center;
justify-content: start;
}

@media (min-width: 768px)
.case-box {
height: 428px;
}

@media (min-width: 1280px)
.case-box {
height: 540px;
}

.case-img {
width: auto;
max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use Bootstrap 4 class .img-fluid for making images responsive (.img-responsive for Bootstrap 3)?

Comment: try all possibilities:
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;

and see which one should work best for you

Answer (score 1):

Set your images with css:

```
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
```

It should adapt them correctly no matter the height of width.

Comment: Yes, but I want the portrait to be as high as the landscape.

Comment: @RASALGHUL Based on the ration you set, your landscape images are always more or less 88.5% of the container height. So just set that as `max-height: 88.5%;` and it should make it. Now if you want an exact fix height for all your image I advice you to use javascript to get all your images, get the one that has the lowest height and set this height to all the other images

Comment: So it's not possible just to get the height from 1920px image and make that to a height?

Comment: The way you made it, is that the height will be `max-height:100%;`  of you container and `width:auto` will take max-width of your container. So the image will keep it scale. But if the image reach 100% of width of container but its height is shorter than container then it won't stretch in height. So this is all based on container size. So this is why if you want to make them all the same height, then you would need to resize your container. As your landscape images seems to be all 1920*1080, it means ratio of 56,25%, so everytime you resize your height you would need to resize the width

Comment: By applying a ratio like: height / 0,5625 = width __or__ width * 0,5625 = height

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating images within a white frame, so they all have the same width and height.. Simple but not the best.